# Boost thread run-time error in Win32 DLL project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-thread

I'm working with a C++ DLL project. I tried to use simple boost thread in there. here is the source-code. this run time exception at `uploadThread = boost::thread(uploadFileThread);` line. Any idea?

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6fa1bd89 (Controller.dll) in UserInterfaces.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf05d.
```

### Controller.h

```
namespace controller{
class  CController {
public: 
boost::thread uploadThread;
}
}
```

### Controller.cpp

```
namespace controller{
static void uploadFileThread(){}
void CController::StartFileUpload(){        
        uploadThread = boost::thread(uploadFileThread);
        uploadThread.join();
}
}
```

### main.cpp

```
int main(){
controller::CController my_Controller;
my_Controller.StartFileUpload();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what, exactly, is wrong from the code you have posted, but you are using uninitialized memory.  The Win32 heap will fill newly allocated memory with `0xBAADF00D` when a debugger is attached.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis- Thank you, I cannot exultantly understand what do you mean by second sentence. could you be kind to explain more.

Comment: On Windows, if a debugger is attached to a process, newly allocated memory is filled with the byte pattern `0xBAADF00D` to help you to identify use of uninitialized memory.  (The Win32 `HeapAlloc` function performs this fill).  The exception message you quote reports that an access violation occurred when attempting to access the memory at address `0xbaadf05d`.  The upper three bytes of this address are almost certainly uninitialized memory.

Comment: That code won't compile - you declare a class `CController` but define a variable of type `Controller`, there are missing semicolons, missing using directives or namespace specifiers etc. Main is supposed to return int, not void. Your class definition is missing the declaration of `StartFileUpload` and so on. Please give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) from the *real* code, so we can see what the real problem is.

Comment: @ArneMertz -  thank you. Corrected the main method.  StartFileUpload is purposely declared as non member function.

Comment: Still won't compile. To help us solve your problem, please be proactive and give us something useful - see the SSCCE link in my last comment. `error: expected ‘;’ after class definition` -- `error: no ‘void controller::CController::StartFileUpload()’ member function declared in class ‘controller::CController’` -- `In function ‘int main()’: error: ‘class controller::CController’ has no member named ‘StartFileUpload’`